# Java Swing positioning elements differently in different operating systems

Tags: java, linux, swing, netbeans

I have written a Java Desktop Application that runs in Windows, Mac OS X, Ubuntu and Open Suse. I am having issues with is positioning thing differently in Linux.

I developed the application with NetBeans using the designer, it looks as I would expect in Windows and Mac OS X, but in the Linux distros certain label controls have shifted into different positions.

Is there a common reason for this?

Comment: Are you using Sun JRE on Linux?

Comment: If I do a "java -version". It reports to be the JRE 1.6.0_15-b03 in Ubuntu and the OpenJDK RE (IcedTea6 1.6.2) in OpenSuse

Comment: Can you post some code for us to review? Not the whole thing, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the Layout style from 'Free Design' to 'Absolute'

Comment: Absolute layout will probably cause as many problems in the long run as free design.  I strongly recommend you dump both and learn to use standard J2SE layouts, nesting them within one another as needed.  See the [Using Layout Managers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) page in the Java Tutorial for further details.  J2SE layouts can be used in the Netbeans form designer.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps Linux uses a different font. One where letters have a different width.

You could try to explicitely set a specific font for your Look&Feel. It should be a font which is installed on all of your target platforms.

Comment: I don't think it is this, the labels dont have text in them, they are being used as containers for images. Also the position change is quite substantial.

Answer (score 1):

The most probable thing is that you use different Look and Feel for every platform. If you're developing in Windows you do layouts to fit for Window style only. But Linux has different L&F with different margins and font for GUI components. Metal style (basic for Linux) and its descendants (Nimbus and GTK+) have larger default system font and heights for components. I think, that must be a reason why you have shiftings.

The way to fix that is to check program looking in both platforms. I'd suggest to develop in Metal style because Windows has smaller fonts, as result, everything which fits in Metal will fit in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you developed the thing on Windows or Mac, that's why it looks "as expected".  Can you compiling/running the code in your IDE on Linux and see how it looks?

My guess is that one of the implementations of the containers is flawed.  I saw this sometimes when I did cross-development and mostly did trial-and-error modifications to fix it (by changing to use other classes).  It also helped to have one developer working in Windows and another in Linux, so that we would easily spot and fix problem areas.